# What is Representation Invariant?

Tags: computer-architecture

I was the book "Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python" and I stumbled upon the concept of representation invariant. What I understood is that the variables (and maybe methods) created inside a class shouldn't be able to be accessed by code outside of the class. Is this definition right? Or I'm completely wrong?